# Owin 'IAppBuilder' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, owin

I am trying to use IAppBuilder on my startup.cs in my MVC Core project, so that I can call app.MapSignalR for my signalR implementation. However I cannot seem to use Owin anywhere in my project, even when I include a using statement or declare it like

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin.IAppBuilder
```

I have tried re-installing the package but that hasn't helped. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: SignalR isn't available for ASP.Net Core yet.

Comment: @DavidG I know they haven't released a complete version yet, but I am using the latest alpha version.

Comment: Then you are using completely the wrong namespaces and middleware commands. You need `services.AddSignalR()` and `app.UseSignalR(...)`. SignalR isn't in the Owin namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the SignalR [sample app](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/samples/ChatSample) which are all part of the [repository](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR) to see how to use this now. Firstly, Owin is not a requirement here and secondly, you don't use `MapSignalR()`. Relevant parts of the `Startup.cs` are:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //snip

    services.AddSignalR();

}
```

And:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //snip

    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes....... //Your routes here
    });

}
```

Comment: Sorry thought i marked this as the answer already. I got it working following your advice.

Comment: No problem, there's no requirement for you to mark anything or upvote, but thanks for coming back :)